# Meteor object properties bound to ngModel are not updated

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I just updated to Angular-Meteor 1.3.0, and updated my code according to [their tutorial](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/3-way-data-binding), as the old ways are deprecated. After I modified my code, changes to my models are no longer saved. In fact, they are not even sent back to the server, I inspected the socket.

Note that when I load my page, the input field is filled with the correct values. Any changes are simply ignored. If i navigate away and back, the field will have the previous value. It's like the databinding is broken, or one-way only. I have the following code (simplified for clarity).

View:

```
<div ng-controller="GoalDetailsCtrl as ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.goal.label"/>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('goalDetails', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'client/components/goals/views/goal-details.html',
        controllerAs: 'goalDetails',
        controller: 'GoalDetailsCtrl'
    }
}).controller('GoalDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $reactive) {
    $reactive(this).attach($scope);
    let reactiveContext = $reactive(this).attach($scope);

    reactiveContext.subscribe('goals');

    reactiveContext.helpers({
        goal: () => Goals.findOne({ _id: $stateParams.goalId }),
        otherGoals: () => Goals.find({ _id: { $not: $stateParams.goalId } })
    });
});
```

Model:

```
Goals = new Mongo.Collection('goals');

// authorization logic
Goals.allow({
    insert: function (userId, goal) {
        return true;
    },
    update: function (userId, goal, fields, modifier) {
        return true;
    },
    remove: function (userId, goal) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a feature naned 'autobind' was removed, explaining why I have this behaviour.